# Huge packet loss in test configuration with docker and ovs

Tags: docker, networking, virtual-machine, kvm, openvswitch

I' have two test scenarios to compare. One is with two VM's, and the second is with two docker containers (with ubuntu images). The picture below shows my scenarios. 1 and 2 are ports: transmitting and receiving. The Tx-br, OVS-D, Rx-br - OpenVSwitch are bridges which I'am using to sending traffic. In VMs/contaiers I'm also using OVS bridge to sending traffic.
I have results but they are strange for me. The scenario with VM's has higher latency than scenario with docker, but docker has higher loss. I can see number of frames sent in a test. In every test, the number of sent frames in docker scenario is smaller than in scenario with VM's. The routing tables in VM and ubuntu container are empty... I think the traffic is sending the same way in scenario with VM and docker, or maybe I'm missing something?? And why in docker scenario is so much frames dropped??

[image: Scenarios]